# Why is possible to pass parameters to a type like in http.Dir(".")?

Tags: go

In http package it is defined a custom type (`type Dir string`) and then a method `Open` is added to it (https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L34). When invoked elsewhere it is done by `http.Dir(".")` as it were a function or method. Can someone explain me why and what is  happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.Dir(".")` is a type conversion. It converts the string `"."` to type `http.Dir`.